# how to update file dynamically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file

I have a file. At starting of Application I read that file now when user update or add some data I am able to add it to the file but only after restarting server the updated data is loaded into memory and available to user. how i can avoid server restart?

```
userFile=new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile());
ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
users =objectMapper.readValue(userFile, Users.class);
Set<Users> userSet=users.getUsers();
User obj=new User("name","id");
userSet.add(obj)
users.setUsers(userSet)
objectMapper.writeValue(new File(userFile.getPath()), users);
```

Comment: Please provide more detail: how do you read that file? How do you write it? How do you access the data that you've read? Ideally [edit] your question to contain a [mre].

Comment: @JoachimSauer i have added code how i am saving file.